# Existence of annihilating polynomials for linear operators on an infinite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am aware of the fact that any linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space is annihilated by some polynomial.

How does the scenario change when the vector space V is assumed to be infinite-dimensional?

In other words, is every linear operator on an infinite dimensional vector space V annihilated too by some polynomial? Or, does there exist at least one linear operator on it which is not annihilated by any polynomial? If there is one, how do we construct such an operator, given any infinite-dimensional V?

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be the real vector space of all real sequences und $T:S \to S$ defined by

$$T(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)=(x_2, x_3,...).$$

If $ \lambda \in \mathbb R$ and $x_{\lambda}:=(1,\lambda, \lambda^2,...)$, Then $Tx_{\lambda}= \lambda x_{\lambda}.$ Thus, each $ \lambda \in \mathbb R$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

Now suppose that there is a polynomial $p \ne 0$ such that $p(T)=0.$ Then we get

$$0=p(T)x _{\lambda}=p( \lambda) x_{\lambda},$$

Since $x_{\lambda} \ne 0,$ this gives $p( \lambda)=0.$ Consequence: each $ \lambda \in \mathbb R$ is a zero of $p$. a contradiction !

Comment: Thanks so much, man. I appreciate it. I have a followup question though. Is it true for any infinite dimensional V via some means of isomorphism between S (in your example) and V?